# MySQL | Related counter on one to many relation

Tags: mysql, performance, query, select, count

### Problem

Is there a way to automatically count related tables (one to Many), where the count will automatically increment / decrement depending if we add or remove a related item.

So, I could obviously just do a COUNT, but for perfomance reason it is expensive millions of records and are queries many many times.
As I solution, rather then count every time, I would actually create a *counter* where **add 1 when adding a new related item or remove 1 when deleting or de-ferencing another item**

In order to do that, I may just create another table that serves as a counter, and query that table without counting.

#### Is there a better way, preferably, that is automatic?

### Example

**schema**

```sql
create table object
(
    object_id       int auto_increment   primary key,
    name            varchar(120)         not null
);


create table item
(
    item_id       varchar(63)         not null,
    object_id int                     not null,
    primary key (object_id, item_id)
);
insert into object (name) VALUES ("hello");
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES
      ("item1", 1),
      ("item2", 1),
      ("item3", 1),
      ("item4", 1);
```

Object "hello" has 4 items:

```sql
select count(*) from item where object_id = 1;
-- ouput: 4
```

However, I found that as a work around, I can create a counter (**that is using back-end Python**) that each time you do a *CRUD* operation, the counter is updated. For example:

**Counter schema**

```sql
create table item_counter
(
    counter bigint                  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    object_id int                   NOT NULL  primary key
)
```

So now the **ORM** in the could we would do something like this (again, it will be handle in Python, but it doesn't matter is just as example:

```sql
-- create object AND item_counter
insert into object (name) VALUES ("hello");
-- create in the same time a counter 
insert into item_counter (object_id) VALUES ((SELECT object_id FROM object where name = "hello"));
-- create items
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES  ("item1", 2);
update item_counter set counter = counter + 1 where object_id = 2;
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES  ("item2", 2);
update item_counter set counter = counter + 1 where object_id = 2;
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES  ("item3", 2);
update item_counter set counter = counter + 1 where object_id = 2;
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES  ("item4", 2);
update item_counter set counter = counter + 1 where object_id = 2;
-- select the counter instead
select counter from item_counter where object_id = 2;
```

That if it was in python it would look like

```py
# pseudo ORM code 
class ItemORM:

    def save(self, item_id, object_id):
        self.orm.save(item_id, object_id)
        counter = self.orm.get_counter(object_id)
        counter.add()
```

So, is there a better way, especially, something that MySQL may do automatically?

#### More Context

In case you want to know why, let's say that I am working in a large code base, which lots of legacy code **and API dependecies used by external clients** and currently there isn't a **counter implementation** but is merely my idea to overcome it. So, changing large part of the code is very risky, instead, tweak come MYSQL tables may be a better solution.

Comment: Use a triggers in mysql to update the new table, that fire on delete and insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task can be easily solved with trigger(s).

For example, if INSERT is the only action on `item` table then only AFTER INSERT trigger needed:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_update_item_count
AFTER INSERT ON item
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE object
SET item_count = ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM item
    WHERE object_id = NEW.object_id 
    )
WHERE object_id = NEW.object_id;
```

[DEMO with complete triggers set](https://dbfiddle.uk/w0G1DO4Z).

Comment: Ok, if no one else comes out these way with another answer this seems to be the accepted one. Before accept to, one question. Using these 3 triggers, how would impact performance? Let's say that we are creating, updating, deleting milions of times a day the *item* record. So having a trigger or not having would it make a big difference you think?

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797444/trigger-performance-degredation-to-use-or-not-to-use

Comment: @FedericoBaù *Using these 3 triggers, how would impact performance?* Of course, triggers decrease the performance for all data modifying queries. But I cannot predict how much it will be, you'd test this. *This is related* - no, the trigger by the link does not use data modifying queries. I think that the difference will be ~2-3 times in your case.

Comment: Why do `COUNT(*)` instead of the much more efficient `item_count = item_count + 1`?

Comment: @RickJames It is more accurate. Even if an incorrect value is placed in the field due to some kind of failure, the next update will fix the incorrectness.